# Pandas qcut error: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `qcut` on a single column. Here is the column:

```
data['Frequency'].head()

0     5
1     5
2    89
3     2
4     1
5     1
6    86
7     1
8    64
9     2
```

However when I try this:

```
data['Frequency_Score'] = pd.qcut(data['Frequency'],5,labels=[1,2,3,4,5],duplicates='drop')`
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

I have tried it with and without the `duplicates='drop'` parameter. Both give errors.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `duplicates="drop"`, the number of actual bins generated may no longer be the same as the bin edge count you desire.

Since you're explicitly declaring 5 labels and end up with 4 bins, you get that error.

Don't specify the labels explicitly:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Frequency": [ 5,  5, 89,  2,  1,  1, 86,  1, 64,  2, ]})
>>> pd.qcut(df["Frequency"], 5, duplicates="drop")
0      (2.0, 5.0]
1      (2.0, 5.0]
2    (68.4, 89.0]
3    (0.999, 2.0]
4    (0.999, 2.0]
5    (0.999, 2.0]
6    (68.4, 89.0]
7    (0.999, 2.0]
8     (5.0, 68.4]
9    (0.999, 2.0]
Name: Frequency, dtype: category
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 2.0] < (2.0, 5.0] < (5.0, 68.4] < (68.4, 89.0]]
>>>
```

Comment: This only gives me 4 labels though. I need to score the column from 1 to 5. In your code there's only 4 categories: `(0.999, 2.0]` which I would relabel as `1`.  `(2.0, 5.0]` would be `2` , `(5.0, 68.4]` would be `3` and `(68.4, 89.0]` would be `4`. I need a `5` as well.

Comment: You can't get 5 quantile bins with your data, that's the issue. When you don't pass `duplicates="drop"`, Pandas warns you about that. When you do, you get less than 5 bins due to duplicate eradication.